# How can I load HTML page in BrowserField?

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I have one HTML page shows map which i want to display in BrowserField.
Here is my code.

```java
BrowserFieldConfig _bfConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
_bfConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
_bfConfig.setProperty( BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE );
_bfConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, "MyApplication 1.0");

BrowserFieldRequest request = new BrowserFieldRequest("page.html");
BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField(_bfConfig);
add(myBrowserField);

myBrowserField.requestContent(request);
```

Comment: is `page.html` a local page (.html file bundled with the app), or a remote page, on the internet, or your local network?

Comment: please provide us details if you really need answer

Comment: thanks for reply.. page.html is local page(.html file is bundled with my app)..

Answer (score 3):

**If the "page.html" is local file then,**

Everything is OK, except here:

```
BrowserFieldRequest request = new BrowserFieldRequest("page.html");
```

Change here like:

```
BrowserFieldRequest request = new BrowserFieldRequest("local:///page.html");
```

you are calling the local file, that why we are giving like this.

Comment: My html page is load map using JavaScript API. Using your suggestion i tried to load map but it's not display and it redirect to another Google page. please can you help me to get solution for that problem??